# Change the metadata of an image in real-time

Tags: image, metadata, server-side

I am working on a personal art project that requires, when the user clicks on an image, its metadata (such as date, geographic location, name, and time) to be altered (to something random) and dynamically presented in real time.

I asked ChatGPT(!), and its suggestion was to use server-side code (e.g., Python, Node.js, or PHP). However, I am not sure how to continue.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Metadata Viewer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style-2.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="imageContainer" onclick="showMetadata()">
        <img id="backgroundImage" src="images/1.jpg" alt="Background Image">
        <div id="metadataOverlay">
            <p id="metadataDate"></p>
            <p id="metadataTime"></p>
            <p id="metadataLocation"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#imageContainer {
    position: relative;
}

#backgroundImage {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#metadataOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: none;
}

#metadataDate,
#metadataTime,
#metadataLocation {
    margin: 0;
}
```